# What IDE I can use for real time editing, no WYSIWIG, just code? Web or FTP based IDE?

Tags: php, html, ide, ftp

Currently I am using cPanel's file manager to access my files, NotePad++ to edit them with syntax highlighting, and uploading them back to the server again using cPanel. Am I doing it wrong (I believe I am)? Is there a better way of doing this. 
I can access my server using FTP.

Comment: Well, you may wish to pick up an FTP client. I've been using Notepad++ and FileZilla (an FTP client) for PHP web development for the past 5 years. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried nearly every IDE out there and the two I liked best were Aptana Studio http://www.aptana.com and Netbeans http://www.netbeans.org

I ended up sticking with Aptana because I liked the dark backgrounds and I had a slight issue with Netbean's code completion.

Both IDEs are free and will allow you to connect through FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has a mode called [Tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) which allows you to edit files remotely. It will take care of transferring them to and fro using some protocol. It has ftp support.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) using the [Remote System Explorer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?nav=%2F53) for that.

You simply have to create a new project and where Eclipse asks for the project location choose RSE, add your FTP/SMB/SSH/... connection and you're good to go.

There's also a [PHP plugin](http://www.phpeclipse.com/) for Eclipse.

If you want to stick to Notepad++, there's also a [FTP plugin](http://www.rarst.net/software/notepadpp-ftp-plugin/) you might want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well on Windows I was using FAR+Colorer+WinSCP (or FTP) plugin for ages exactly for the online editing.
It is not an IDE but just a file explorer(a powerful one)/text editor though.